# External WFS in GeoServer returns error

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I add an external WFS (https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?version=1.1.0) as source in GeoServer. Then I add a layer of the external WFS in GeoServer (se_Halderberge_Synergiegebieden). When I preview this WFS in GeoServer a get an error.

```
2020-10-12 12:20:47,383 ERROR [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?request=GetFeature&PROPERTYNAME=synergiegebied&FILTER=%3Cogc%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22+xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%3E%3Cogc%3ABBOX%3E%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3Esynergiegebied%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E4.453754+51.493864%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E4.586277+51.626215%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Fogc%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E&TYPENAME=se%3AHalderberge_Synergiegebieden&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fjson&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS
2020-10-12 12:20:47,383 ERROR [geotools.rendering] - org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSException: WFS returned an exception. Originating Request: GET_FEATURE[
    handle: GeoTools 19.2(65573d34f5a7da06abb3b793026d4b1c09af616a) WFS 1.1.0 DataStore @obsnode108.internal.cloudapp.net#49
    outputFormat: <application/json>
    method: GET
    onlineResource: <https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?>
    final URL: <https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?request=GetFeature&PROPERTYNAME=synergiegebied&FILTER=%3Cogc%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22+xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%3E%3Cogc%3ABBOX%3E%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3Esynergiegebied%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E4.453754+51.493864%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E4.586277+51.626215%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Fogc%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E&TYPENAME=se%3AHalderberge_Synergiegebieden&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fjson&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS>
]
    [OperationParsingFailed: [Cannot parse provided filter text]]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSException: WFS returned an exception. Originating Request: GET_FEATURE[
    handle: GeoTools 19.2(65573d34f5a7da06abb3b793026d4b1c09af616a) WFS 1.1.0 DataStore @obsnode108.internal.cloudapp.net#49
    outputFormat: <application/json>
    method: GET
    onlineResource: <https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?>
    final URL: <https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?request=GetFeature&PROPERTYNAME=synergiegebied&FILTER=%3Cogc%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22+xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%3E%3Cogc%3ABBOX%3E%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3Esynergiegebied%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E4.453754+51.493864%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E4.586277+51.626215%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Fogc%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E&TYPENAME=se%3AHalderberge_Synergiegebieden&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fjson&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS>
]
    [OperationParsingFailed: [Cannot parse provided filter text]]
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:45)
    at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:31)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2408)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:1995)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:857)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:569)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:269)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:136)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:720)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:300)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:123)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:252)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor339.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:59)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:72)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy268.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:877)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:208)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerAuthenticationKeyFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAuthenticationKeyFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I focussed on the error: "`Cannot parse provided filter text"`. When I check the url, I can't explain where this filter comes from:

```
<https://ogc.synergienl.com/wfs?
request=GetFeature
&PROPERTYNAME=oid,status,naam,synergiescore,synergietijd,synergielocatie,datumafstemming,opmerking,deeln_gem,opm_gem,deeln_gas,opm_gas,deeln_wat,opm_wat,deeln_elek,opm_elek,deelnpartijen,uitvoeringsjaargemeente,uitvoeringsjaarnuts,eerstejaar,laatstejaar,aantaljaren,coordinator,typewerkzaamheden,gemeente,waterbedrijf,gasnetbeheerder,elektranetbeheerder,laatstgewijzigdop,ingevoerdop,gewijzigddoor,ingevoerddoor,synergiegebied
&FILTER=<ogc:Filter+xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
+xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
+xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<ogc:BBOX><ogc:PropertyName/>
<gml:Envelope+srsDimension="2"
+srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml%234326">
<gml:lowerCorner>4.453914+51.478591</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>4.604518+51.562625</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope></ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>
&TYPENAME=se:Halderberge_Synergiegebieden
&REQUEST=GetFeature
h&RESULTTYPE=HITS
&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json
&VERSION=1.1.0
&MAXFEATURES=1000000
&SERVICE=WFS>
```

I changed some settings in the source (added some extra parameters) and the layer but the result is the same.

Does anyone recognises this problem or can I explain why the filter is added?

Comment: The BBOX filter is probably set by GeoServer and it is the extent of the map in the preview window. The purpose is that GeoServer does not request the whole feature type each time but just what is needed.

Comment: The WFS server you're referring to is password protected, so, no way to check what is going on.